# Setting a jQuery dialog semi-transparent

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've looked through and haven't exactly found what I need (probably due to my lack of CSS/jQuery skill), so here goes.  I'm trying to create some help type "bubbles" using jQuery dialogs that are semi-transparent.  I've tried using `.fadeTo()` and `.css("opacity", n)` but the dialog appears with a white background while the content does indeed bleach out, rather than the entire dialog being semi-transparent.

Here's what I have so far.  Note there is a `<div id="HelpWindow">` on the page that contains the content and the dialog itself works just fine.

```
        $('#HelpWindow').dialog({
            width: 600,
            height: 420,
            position: "center",
            show: {
                effect: "fade",
                duration: 300,
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "fade",
                duration: 200,
            }
        }).css("opacity", 0.5);
```

I don't need it for all dialogs on the page, just the help "bubble".  Apologies if this is a stupid question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#HelpWindow').dialog({
...
}).parents(".ui-dialog").css("opacity", "0.5");
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it worked just fine once I removed the `fade` effect, which seemed to make it jump to full opacity, but then randomly to the appropriate level.  Marking as accepted.  I'd upvote your answer but I don't have enough rep :(

Comment: You can see why: the fade is accomplished by screwing with the opacity.

Comment: Yes, I thought it might have been my original problem but clearly it wasn't.  Thanks again for your help!